# jQuery cycle plugin - Is there a way to know when pager is ready?

Tags: jquery, jcarousel, jquery-cycle

I'm trying to use [Malsup's jQuery Cycle plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/) with [jCarousel](http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/) to allow thumbnails in my pagination to scroll horizontally and it's working fine. The problem is that sometimes the jcarousel plugin doesn't initialize because I believe the pagination is not ready yet. My code looks like this:

```
$('#slideshow').cycle({
    timeout : 0,
    speed   : 1000,
    pager   : '#image-carousel ul',
    pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, slide) {
        return '<li><a href="#"><img src="' + slide.src + '" width="107" height="80" /></a></li>'; 
    }
});

$('#image-carousel').jcarousel();
```

Sometimes when the page loads the jcarousel doesn't work, I used setTimeout to delay its initialization about 2 seconds and it worked every time so I assume it must be because sometimes the pager is not ready yet. I can live with the setTimeout solution for now but I think there must be a better way to handle this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to get around it, if you're comfortable with altering the cycle plugin's source code, you could include a callback called `onPagerBuilt` (or something) to be run after the pagination is built. Alter the `buildPager()` function in cycle.js like so:

```
function buildPager(els, opts) {
    var $p = $(opts.pager);
    $.each(els, function(i,o) {
        $.fn.cycle.createPagerAnchor(i,o,$p,els,opts);
    });
    opts.updateActivePagerLink(opts.pager, opts.startingSlide, opts.activePagerClass);

        // add this line
        if (typeof opts.onPagerBuilt == 'function') opts.onPagerBuilt();
};
```

Then you'll want to add a default to `$.fn.cycle.defaults` somewhere in that list:

```
$.fn.cycle.defaults = {
  onPagerBuilt: null, // the callback to be run after pagination is built.

  // rest of the default options
  //...
}
```

Then your script would be like so:

```
$('#slideshow').cycle({
    timeout : 0,
    speed   : 1000,
    pager   : '#image-carousel ul',
    pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, slide) {
        return '<li><a href="#"><img src="' + slide.src + '" width="107" height="80" /></a></li>'; 
    },
    onPagerBuilt: function () {
        $('#image-carousel').jcarousel();
    }
});
```